# How can I change the view from portrait to landscape mode?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to change first view in portrait mode and the second view comes in landscape mode, I am using the `gameconfig.h` file.

The code is:

```
//
//  GameConfig.h
//  Cocos2DSimpleGame
//
//  Created by Ray Wenderlich on 11/21/10.
//  Copyright Ray Wenderlich 2010. All rights reserved.
//

#ifndef __GAME_CONFIG_H
#define __GAME_CONFIG_H

//
// Supported Autorotations:
//      None,
//      UIViewController,
//      CCDirector
//
#define kGameAutorotationNone 0
#define kGameAutorotationCCDirector 1
#define kGameAutorotationUIViewController 2  //2
//
// Define here the type of autorotation that you want for your game
//
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationUIViewController


#endif // __GAME_CONFIG_H


and in my appDelegate file is: 
#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
#else
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];

    //[director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
//  [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
#endif
```

In the first view I want to show the menu in portrait mode, and also when I click on the new game then the game will show in landscape mode. I use also `shouldAutoInterfaceOrientation`, but I've not found the solution.

Comment: Please format your code. It's really hard to read it like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I easily Solve my problem with the help of #define kGameAutorotationUIViewController 2 view whenever I change its value to 1 the orientation is portrait mode and when I change its value the view will show in landscape mode, thnx for giving me the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

when you want to change orientation, call this function:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```